# Plastic tailpiece on brass bathtub drain?

Tags: drain, bathtub

I have a new tub that came with the drain & overflow pre-assembled, but no tailpiece. I found a plastic tailpiece for $5 and I would like to know (1) if it's OK to use on this drain and (2) how to install it correctly. (The tailpiece packaging just says "plastic"; can I assume since it's black that it's ABS?)

The drain itself looks like brass. I have access underneath the tub, so no problem there.

The tailpiece came with a nut and two washers. Is this how I should fit them together (see photo)? Should I apply putty or anything else (I think not)? I tested just the nut on the drain, and it seems like a snug fit. [**EDIT:** When I try to assemble everything as shown, it doesn't fit because the nut threads can't reach the threads on the drain. So basically, I have no idea how to connect this tailpiece.][**EDIT #2:** After watching a YouTube video "How to replace a sink tailpiece" (StackExchange won't let me link directly), I removed the extra washer that I had slid down the tailpiece. See the red X's on the photos. Now it fits. Hopefully there won't be any leaks. Comments are welcome!]

[image]

Then of course there is the P-trap. I'm just planning to slip the tailpiece into the adapter and tighten. I'll probably shorten and debur the tailpiece first, though.

[image]

Does this all look OK? Would a brass tailpiece be safer (less likely to leak)? I'd like to avoid problems as much as possible. Thanks so much for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably nylon, but it's all fine. Almost every concealed drain uses plastic of one type or another these days.

Those fittings are all compression-actuated. Often the entire trap is also so it can be disassembled for cleaning when needed. Don't use caulk or putty. Tighten them about as tight as you can get them by hand (unless you're a bricklayer).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Unfortunately I was wrong when I said the tailpiece fits snugly on the drain -- I had only tested the slip nut at that point. When I try to attach the entire tailpiece, it doesn't fit (see edit). So it's back to the drawing board. I guess I need to find another tailpiece.

Comment: You have an extra washer at the top of the tailpiece. Just use the upper one. I didn't catch that earlier.

Comment: Ah perfect, I just edited the question after learning about this mistake from YouTube. Thanks for confirming. The job isn't finished yet, but you answered my questions so I'll mark this accepted.

Comment: Hey, the job is now complete and everything works like a charm, no leaks. Thanks again for the help!